# Detect ip with zsh or console

Tags: console, ip, zsh

I'm trying to do some script with zsh for detect the ip and launch a script, something like that:
( there're alot of ways to get the ip, for example I get something like this: )

```
ifconfig | awk '/inet / {sub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print $2}' | tail -1
```

The question is: How I can compare the output with some string for creating a conditional...

```
ifconfig | awk '/inet / {sub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print $2}' | tail -1 == 172.*
```

I try the '==' but this fails so hard...

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `...|tail -1|grep 172`?

Comment: @Marc B yes, true. But how can this returns me a true or a false? For a conditional structure? :x

Answer (score 0):

You could try using grep.
If you are trying to look for ip that has 172 in it, the following command will work.

ifconfig | awk '/inet / {sub(//.*/, "", $2); print $2}' | tail -1 | grep 172 | wc -l

However, if you want to check if ip starts with 172, the just a little change will work just fine.

ifconfig | awk '/inet / {sub(//.*/, "", $2); print $2}' | tail -1 | grep 172.* | wc -l

Comment: Yes, but How can I write this grep for returning me a true or false ?

Comment: It wont give you a true or false, but it will give you an answer as '1' or '0'. 1 implies true and 0 implies false. Will this serve your purpose or you need the output to be 'true' or 'false' only?

Comment: Try this: ifconfig | awk '/inet / {sub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print $2}' | tail -1 | grep -q 172  && echo true || echo false

Comment: Nah, the problem is that grep outputs something, watching man grep I find -q option it's output nothing...

Comment: -q is for quiet, basically it suppresses the output of grep. Without -q you will get the output as the ipaddress and then true. With -q option, you will get the output only as true or false

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if statement with `|` fails so hard...

The solve is...
If u assign a variable with the result of the grep with -q u can compare with -eq to true or false!